# DataGrid.BeginningEdit event not firing when I use TextBox in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to show data in data grid. And only some of the cells in a column can be edited.So, for this purpose I defined the Column template for one column as shown below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"  BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger= LostFocus}"></TextBox>
   </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So, depending upon the read only property of the model object, cell will be editable or not.This is working great.But now I want to perform some operation when user starts editing the cell, so I created a handler for the BeginningEdit event for the DataGrid.But the event handler is not getting called.I replaced the TextBox with DataGridCell.Now, the event handler is called, but I can't edit the cell value.So, how do I solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `<asp:TextBox>` ?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah I am using wpf, this tag is no available in this framework.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, haven't worked on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the Cell**Editing**Template that is applied when the cell is put into edit mode, which is when the `BeginningEdit` event occurs, so you should add your `TextBox` to this one:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"  BorderThickness="0" 
                     Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger= LostFocus}"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I've referenced your above solution on my similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61603559/1232087). Instead of TextBox I am using `DatePicker`.

Comment: Your solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636423/1232087) worked like a charm (thank you).

Comment: Agreed. You deserve that.