# DataGrid CellEditEnding event not firing on a cell editing inside DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-core

In the `MyDatagrid_CellEditEnding(...)` event (shown below) I am capturing the edited value of a cell whenever a cell of one of the three columns is edited by a user. After editing cell in second or third column, when I move out of that cell, I can see the `CellEditEnding` event getting called. But the same is not true for the first column that is a `DataGridTemplateColumn` column. That is, when I change a date in any cell in the first `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and move the cursor out of the cell, the `CellEditEnding` event is not called.

**Question**: What I may be missing here and how can we make it work? I have seen similar issues and their solutions online (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47353939/1232087) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate?view=netcore-3.1)), so I'm not sure what I may be missing here.

**Note**: I'm using latest versions of `VS2019` and `.NET Core 3.1` on `Windows 10 vs1903 - Pro`

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        .....
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" CellEditEnding="MyDatagrid_CellEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Modified">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified}" BorderThickness="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified}" BorderThickness="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code**:

```
......
......
string _sDateModified;
string _sFirstName;
string _sLastName;
.....
.....
private void MyDatagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridColumn c = e.Column;
    if (c.Header.ToString() == "Date Modified")
        _sDateModified = (e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text;
    else if (c.Header.ToString() == "First Name")
        _sFirstName = (e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text;
    else if (c.Header.ToString() == "Last Name")
        _sLastName = (e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are editing the `DatePicker` in the `CellTemplate` and this doesn't cause the `CellEditEnding` event to fire. The `CellTemplate` is not supposed to contain any input controls.

Replace the `DatePicker` in the `CellTemplate` with a `TextBlock`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Modified">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateModified, StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" BorderThickness="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or set the `IsEnabled` property of the `DatePicker` in the `CellTemplate` to `false`. Either way, you'll have to enter the edit mode by double clicking on the cell before you can expect the `CellEditEnding` event to fire.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" BorderThickness="0" />
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```